# Как сделать кнопку двух цветов

Tags: css, css3

Привет помогите с css для кнопки,
как можно сделать такую же кнопку 
[image: кнопка двух цветов а по центру смесь их вместе]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот неплохой пример https://css-tricks.com/examples/GradientBorder/ , только нужно подобрать нужные вам цвета. Ещё вот https://css-tricks.com/gradient-borders-in-css/ там есть и примеры с codepen